# android fire event or wait for status change in loop

Tags: android, service, binding

I have question regarding the service and activity.
I have one service which calls some other class to get contacts from phone, and activity where the contacts will be placed. What is the best thing to do:
1 this: On bound Activity "ask" in infinite loop for status from service like this:

Thread trdTest = new Thread(new Runnable() {

```
public void run() {
                boolean done= true;
                while(done){
                    if (service.status == Constants.GETTING_CONTACTS_DONE_OK){
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                        done= false;
                    }else if (service.status == Constants.GETTING_CONTACTS_ERROR_NOTOK){
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                        done= false;
                    }
                }
            }});
     trdTest.start();
```

2: this: Create cistom event in service and fire event when getting users is done. Of course the bounded activity will listen for that event

Thanx for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running loops like that will probably slow down many things and is not a good idea. The second approach seems to me like a much better idea.